# How to handle with url link on jeditable field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jeditable

I have jeditable text field like below.

How to handle with links in text.
Right now when I click on link it starts editing it instead of opening the link.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without a working example, but you can try to override jeditable's click behavior like this:

```
$("#yourEditable a").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.open($(this).attr("href"));
});
```